# Why is Pydev giving a syntax error for built-in keywords?

Tags: python, eclipse, syntax-error, pydev

Why is Pydev giving me syntax errors for built-in python functions like str()?

> Undefined variable: str
>
> Undefined variable: False
>
> Undefined variable: float

Comment: code? does python even need you to id if its a str or float?

Comment: print(str("hi")) will give a syntax error on str.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str `str(object)`

Comment: I do not get any error for that. maybe you have a problem with Pydev configuration?

Comment: Your python interpreter was not configured properly

Comment: @pylover Any idea what could not be configured properly within the interpreter?

Comment: @joaquin Any idea what could cause the problem in the configuration?

Comment: Follow the installation procedures indicated in pydev [documentation](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html) and check you defined/loaded your project, set your interpreter, paths, etc as indicated there.

Comment: I had this problem under Windows 7, when there was not enough empty space on drive C: (Python27 was installed on C:). Freeing some space and re-starting Eclipse solved the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove and re-add the python interpreter in the PyDev configuration. Make sure that the project is using the newly added interpreter.

Comment: This had no effect on freshly installed Aptana 3.6 PyDev running OS X 10.11 . I am still getting "Undefined variable: None". I had not choice but to revert to Aptana 3.4.

Comment: I tried that, it did not fix the problem using python 3.4 in an anaconda environment.

Answer (score 3):

This means that there's a  problem with starting the shell to get completions
for builtins (usually a firewall or a misconfiguration in the network -- see: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F which may give you hints on how to solve it).

Also, please add details on your error log if you're unable to solve it (see:
http://pydev.org/faq.html#how_do_i_report_a_bug for details on getting
the error log).

Comment: That's interesting, but I don't have a problem with the hanging completions. It's more a matter of built-ins not being recognized. This is a difficult one to reproduce, but if it happens again I will report the bug.

Comment: @Fabio I've had both, and actually your first link led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those ppl who are using **Aptana** and have the same Problem:

I upgraded Aptana and PyDev with the following instructions:

[Update PyDev on Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25971061/4150548)

after the upgrade PyDev worked just fine for me :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.