# PyDev-Eclipse Shows Error but Code Runs Fine

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I have just installed PyDev into eclipse and tried writing a hello world application. But eclipse underline even the `print` function and gives message of `print:undefined variable` on hover. But the code works fine. When I run the application it runs fine and prints `Hello World` on console. I am attaching the screenshot for reference
[image]
Please note that I have come across [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099380/why-is-pydev-giving-a-syntax-error-for-built-in-keywords) and proposed solution of removing and re-adding the interpreter did not work for me. I am on Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine if that matters.
**Edit**
I have following entries in python interpreter's tab
[image]

Comment: Can you check if you have some error in your error log? See: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F -- This seems an issue finding the 'print' name in the builtins -- see if it's related to: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved by removing all the interpreters, including them again and recreating the project. Please note that project created before removing/adding interpreters still showed error. So I removed them as well and created a new project which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, so following suggestions of:
[PyDev Docs](http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-WhenIdoacodecompletion%2CPyDevhangs%2CwhatcanIdo%3F)

I added missing LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Window->Preferences->Python Interpreter (Environment tab), and then closed and reopened the project (no need to recreate the project).  Once I reopen the files that had errors, the errors were gone.